# VPS Contabo - Vesta

Tags: linux, debian, хостинг, vps, vesta

Всем привет.

Устанавливаю Vesta по инструкции:

`curl -O http://vestacp.com/pub/vst-install.sh`

`bash vst-install.sh --force`

Ввожу почту, ввожу домен.

Но возникает ошибка при установке, что делать?

```
E: Package 'apache2.2-common' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-ruid2
E: Package 'libapache2-mod-php5' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'php5' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'php5-common' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package php5-cgi
E: Package 'php5-mysql' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'php5-curl' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'mysql-client' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package phpMyAdmin
E: Package 'rssh' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package vesta
E: Unable to locate package vesta-nginx
E: Unable to locate package vesta-php
E: Unable to locate package vesta-ioncube
E: Unable to locate package vesta-softaculous
Error: apt-get install failed
```

Comment: На какой версии ОС вы это делаете?

Comment: Версия ОС Debian 9

Comment: Покажите содержимое файлов `/etc/issue` и `/etc/debian_version`